# Docker Image for pythpon selenium UI testing

Tags: selenium-webdriver, dockerfile

Is there a good docker image (that I can inherit using FROM) which is helpful for headless browser testing using python Selenium?

Comment: try using `Xvfb` if you are working with linux environment.Hope this might help you http://elementalselenium.com/tips/38-headless

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this](https://github.com/pr4bh4sh/selendocker/), I have used the official distributions. If you need to change the settings inside the node you need to get the base Dockerfile of the node and perform the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try the official docker images from Selenium at https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium; you may also need this https://github.com/elgalu/docker-selenium